# How many items I can / can I add?

Tags: grammar, questions

How to say correctly: How many items **I can / can I** add?

Help, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How many items can I add?

This is correct.

Questions are **verb subject** order. Statements are usually **subject verb** order.

Examples:

> Are you well?
>
> I am well.
>
> Can you go?
>
> I can go.